# sencha touch modern developer mobile terminal, textfield display exception

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs6-modern

The development of the mobile terminal landing interface, the runtime found that the text input box display abnormal. If you put the code in toolbar to show no problem, the house ah formPanel shows weird, the effect is as follows
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgzZH.png)

mycode：

```
Ext.define('GasApp.view.main.login.Login',{
    extend : 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype : 'loginView',
    requires: [
        'Ext.field.Password',
        'Ext.Button',
        'Ext.field.Toggle',
        'Ext.layout.HBox',
        'Ext.Toast',
        'GasApp.view.main.login.Controller'
    ],
    alternateClassName: 'loginView',
    controller : 'loginCtrl',
    listeners: {
        initialize: 'onLoginInitialize'
    },
    config:{
        padding: '40 30 0 30',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'account',
            ui : 'text_',
            label: '账号',
            clearIcon:true,
            required: true
        },{
            xtype: 'passwordfield',
            name: 'password',
            label: '密码',
            required: true
        },{
            items: [{
                xtype: 'togglefield',
                name: 'persist',
                label: '记住我',
                labelTextAlign: 'right',
                labelAlign: 'left',
                value: true
            }]
        },{
            xtype: 'button',
            width: '100%',
            text: '登&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;陆',
            ui: 'action',
            listeners: {
                tap: 'onLoginClick'
            }
        }]
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks ok to me: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2aop Post a fiddle.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli It is not a problem to run on the fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2aop , but the effect I run locally is not consistent with the effect that you give the address. What's the problem? Is the style inconsistent?

Comment: My point is that there's some problem that you're not showing in your question, so I can't answer it.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli o thanks ，I'll try other ways.